# How to define the __str__ function while using type to create a class?

Tags: python, metaclass

I am trying to achieve the following case:

```
    class ABCD(object):
        def __str__(self): 
            return "some string"

    a=ABCD()
    print a
    some string
```

Using type:

```
    A=type("A",(object,),dict(__str__="some string",h=5))
    a=A()
    print a
```

But get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: ... it needs to be a *function* not a *string*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to pass a callback? `__str__` is to be implemented as an **instance method** that **returns** a string.

```
A = type("A",(object,), dict(__str__=lambda self: "some string" , h=5))
a = A()
```

```
print(a)
some string
```

When you call `print` on an object, its `__str__` method is called. If the object does not have one defined, the the `__str__` for the `object` class is invoked. So, you shouldn't assign a string to `__str__` because python'll try to "call" it as a function, throwing a `TypeError`.